# Why do we need invariance of domain to conclude that the neighborhood in the definition of a manifold is open?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I'm reading Spivak's first differential geometry text. Spivak claims that in the definition of a manifold, the neighborhood $U\cong\mathbb{R}^n$ of a point $x$ must be an open set, and that this follows from invariance of domain. I'm almost certainly missing something obvious, but I don't see why we need invariance of domain for this. Here's what I was thinking:

Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a continuous map $\phi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\phi(U)=\mathbb{R}^n$ (since $\phi$ is surjective). It follows that $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)=U$ is open, since the preimage of the open set $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open.

What's wrong with this argument, which doesn't use invariance of domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this argument is that all you've shown is that $U$ is open in $U$ in the subspace topology, which is true of any space. If it had a neighborhood isomorphic to the Cantor set instead of $\mathbb R^n$, that neighborhood would be open, at least in itself.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thanks for the clear explanation. I'll accept once the waiting period expires.

Comment: @csch2 I wasn't aware there is a waiting period. I mean, I'm not trying to coerce you into accepting, but usually you're able to accept an answer as soon as it's posted. The exception is if it is your own answer, in which case you have to wait two days.

Comment: When I tried to accept I was told I needed to wait another three minutes to accept (probably because you answered the question so soon after it was posted).

Comment: @csch2 No problem. Thanks, and feel free to unaccept and accept another answer, etc., as you wish.